# 401 Authentication issue with BeanStream Payment Gateway API

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, beanstream

I have been trying to integrate BeanStream payment gateway with my product from last three days. But unfortunately I am getting 401 authentication error every time. I have performed following steps.

- 1) Created a test account.
- 2) Generated API Pass Code from Configuration -> Payment Profile Configuration -> Security Settings.
- 3) Got merchant Id from top section.
- 4) Created an HttpWeb request using the sample code provided on BeanStream developer portal. Below is the code for that.

  ```
  string url = "https://www.beanstream.com/api/v1/payments";
  BeanStreamRequest req = new BeanStreamRequest
  {
      order_number = "10000123",
      amount = 100.00m,
      payment_method = "",
      card = new Card {
          name = "abc",
          number = "5100000010001004",
          expiry_month = "02",
          expiry_year = "18",
          cvd = "642"
      }
  };

  JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  string jsonString = js.Serialize(req);

  string merchantId = "MERCHANT_ID";
  string apiPassCode = "API_PASS_CODE";
  string base64_encode = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",merchantId,":",apiPassCode);
  string authorization = String.Format("{0}{1}", "Passcode ", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64_encode)));
  HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  webRequest.Method = "POST";
  webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
  webRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = authorization;
  //webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization ", authorization);
  webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
  webRequest.ContentLength = jsonString.Length;

  StreamWriter writer = null;
  writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
  writer.Write(jsonString);
  writer.Close();

  string responseString;
  try
  {
      using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
      {
          using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
          {
              responseString = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
          }
      }
  }
  catch (WebException ex)
  {
      if (ex.Response != null)
      {
          using (HttpWebResponse errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response)
          {
              using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
              {
                  string remoteEx = reader.ReadToEnd();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that you are creating an API Key (Passcode) for a Payment Profile API (http://developer.beanstream.com/documentation/tokenize-payments/) and then using it in a Payments API (http://developer.beanstream.com/documentation/take-payments/). These two resources use different API Keys (Passcodes). See "Where is my API Passcode?" on http://developer.beanstream.com/documentation/your-first-integration/. Create an API Key for Payments API and everything should work as expected.